# Define interface name by running a bash script with udev rules

Tags: udev

I want to ged rid of random interface names when I stick in a usb-lte-dongle and want to determine the name of the interface programmatically.

I thought it would be easiest to get a potential name with the help of an external bash script. I read somewhere that it is possible to save the result of the script in ENV{MY_VAR} by assigning it to "%c" which is actually not working.

I monitored it with udevadm -e and the MY_VAR is empty

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", IMPORT{program}="/some/determined_name.sh", ENV{MY_VAR}="%c"
```

In another line I wanted to read MY_VAR and assign it to the interface name. This is also not working:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", NAME=ENV{MY_VAR}
```

Any Hints?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", Program="/some/determined_name.sh", NAME="%c"
```

I fist thought it should be something with

```
IMPORT{program}
```

but that was somehow misleading